# Composer: google-api-php-client does not exist in any version

Tags: php, composer-php, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to install the `google-api-php-client` on a Windows system (for local testing) using Composer.

But when I run `composer require google-api-php-client:2.0@RC` in my project directory, Composer states that

> The requested package google-api-php-client could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

The command I ran is directly from [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples#4_install_your_dependencies). I've searched both StackOverflow and the rest of the Internet for someone with the same problem but haven't found anyone. However, I was able to install a previous version of another similar Google package (which doesn't meet my needs) so I know that Composer *is* connecting to the database.

Comment: Can you try to run `composer -v` and see if more useful information comes out?

Comment: @Nick Version 1.0 dev from 2015-12-28

Comment: Sorry, I mean to ask you to attempt to run the composer tool with [verbose output](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global-options).

Comment: @nick "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
 - The requested package google-api-php-client could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name."

Comment: Are you running this in the windows command line?

Comment: This is not a composer problem the documentation is wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package is called: `google/apiclient`

You can check it on the [github repository](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/#composer).